# Convert Varchar to time format

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have tried the links available here for similar questions before but it does not work. So I am posting my case here. very tired.

i have varchar in format 1 Hour 30 Minutes.
  i want to convert this to time format hh:mm:ss. (01:30:00)

can you please help ?

Comment: You're looking for MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
select maketime(col + 0, substring_index(col, 'Hour ', -1) + 0, 0)
```

These should extract the hour and minute components of your string, convert them to numbers and turn them into a time.

Comment: thankyou you are very helpful, and then i want to sum them with result time format (hh:mm:ss) because when i used "select SUM(maketime(col + 0, substring_index(col, 'Hour ', -1) + 0, 0))"; the result isn't time

Comment: @SandhiZukhruf . . . Your question is not about aggregation.  If you have a question about aggregating times, then ask *another* question.  Include sample data and desired results, as well as a good description of the question.  This answer appears to answer this question.